# Azure Function not deserializing object

Tags: c#, json, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

In the latest version of Azure Functions I am unable to get a function to deserialize an object on its way in.

**Versions:**

Azure Functions Core Tools: **1.0.0-beta.100**

Function Runtime Version: **1.0.11015.0**

Visual Studio: **15.3.0 Preview 4.0**

Example (Not Working):

```
[FunctionName("Login")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log, AuthenticatingUser user)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user.Username);
    });
}
```

When attempting to use Postman to post to this function, I always get the following error:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.Login. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'user'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value was provided for parameter 'user'.

I have tried posting with form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded and raw (with JSON selected - what i expected to work). All end up with the same error.

When I take out the user from the function, I can access the JSON being passed in via:

```
var content = req.Content;
string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

In previous versions of Azure Functions (notable **not** built using the Visual Studio extension, involves JSON files, etc) this worked as expected.

I'm posting various versions of the following:

```
{
    "Username": "myUserName",
    "Password": "MyPassword123"
}
```

Model for the user:

```
public class AuthenticatingUser
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mark `user` parameter with `HttpTrigger` attribute:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(
    HttpRequestMessage req, 
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] AuthenticatingUser user)
```

`req` will still be populated without any attribute on it.

Make sure your request's `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`. Given that, the function will work with your JSON in request body.

Comment: Embarrassing mistake on my part. Worked flawlessly - thank you.